# How to pass parameter in URL from JSP to JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am using rewriting URL for passing the parameter from JSP to servlet. Now I want to pass an already passed URL parameter from JSP to jQuery. For that I tried the below code. Initially it was working fine but afterwards, I don't know what happened, it is not working.

```
var jspo = <%=request.getParameter("pono")%>
            $.get('BillItemJson', {
                pono: jspo
            }, function (response) {
                alert('post');
                var select = $('#A');
                select.find('option').remove();
                $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                    $('<option>').val(index).text(value).appendTo(select);
                });
            });
```

Please help so that I can make AJAX call for loading the drop-down. I am using jQuery 1.10.2 and JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud declare variable `jspo` value in quotes:

```
var jspo = '<%=request.getParameter("pono")%>';
```